# Raspbian, Hanns.G HT231HPB and chromium browser

Tags: touchscreen, keyboard, chromium, kiosk

I am using the set up above as a dumb terminal/kiosk my issue is that the Chromium on screen keyboard is offsetting the touch so that you can't accurately type. I know the monitor is operating as a single point touch and was wondering if changing the operating system to Windows 10 IOT, which the monitor claims should operate at 10 point touch would increase the accuracy, or if a system driven OSK would be better? At the moment the whole unit is close to unusable. I have calibrated the screen and have tried other methods, but feel I am running out of options.

Comment: Have tried matchbox-keyboard, this morning with little success

Comment: Have now tried the same set up (Chrome browser with keyboard extension) on a Windows 10 box and it is a different beast, the touch capabilities are greatly improved, I would still appreciate any guidance as to whether I can get the same results out of IOT on the PI 3, or do I just get a mini PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coaxed the IOT version into life, and compared the touch functionality to both a PI running Raspbian and  a mini PC running full Windows 10. The 2 Windows devices had comparable results but the the screen was specifically designed for it. Now experimenting with a Javascript OSK (on screen keyboard) to mimic the readily available Chrome plug in

Comment: The mini PC has proved unreliable due to Windows updates, as a kiosk it requires too much downtime and then a complicated reboot. The PI on the other hand seems to be the better solution as the IOT update drops the whole system and the restarts properly (using a combination of a headless browser and the IOTStartup although you do have to clear previous versions of the app thoroughly.)